# How to bring files from the upload directory to the media gallery?

Tags: post-thumbnails, media, media-library

My wordpress theme creates thumbnails of media files that I upload into my posts.  These thumbnails are not accessible inside the media gallery, they exist only in the media upload directory.  I want to access these thumbnail files in my media gallery.

How do I import files in my upload directory into media gallery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a one-off batch operation, you can use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/

But first you should figure out why they don't show up in the first place. Maybe complain to the theme developer.

Comment: This is a premium theme with support, I requested support from them and they told me that the issue was not related to the theme.  But I do agree that if they added this functionality in the theme, they should have added the thumbnails into the media gallery.  I will check with them.